# Spring Boot non-embedded Derby database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, derby

How do I configure Spring Boot to connect to a network-based Derby database?  I do not want an embedded Derby DB to be used, however it is constantly trying to load the EmbeddedDriver class.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver from ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4d6c3502;ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4d6c3502
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:280)
```

I have the following in my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyTestDb
spring.datasource.username=Eric
spring.datasource.password=eric
spring.datasource.initialize=false
```

And my pom has the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        <version>10.11.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

My Application.java class is boilerplate:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableCaching
public class Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setShowBanner(false);
       app.run(args);
    }
}
```

Is there some additional special config I have to do?

Comment: You might need to add your driver class to your configuration properties too: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database

Comment: @XtremeBiker I just noticed that as well.  I tried adding the driver class and I think it is working; still have to validate though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alluded to by @XtremeBiker, I was missing the driver class name in the application.properties file to force Spring to use the client driver and not the Embedded driver (by default)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyTestDb
spring.datasource.username=Eric
spring.datasource.password=eric
spring.datasource.initialize=false
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
```

Comment: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver is not in         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.15.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

The below config works for me

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
    
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDbTest
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
```